# SQL like GROUP BY AND HAVING

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to get the counts of groups which satisfy a certain condition. In SQL terms, I want to do the following in Elasticsearch.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
   SELECT
    senderResellerId,
    SUM(requestAmountValue) AS t_amount
   FROM
    transactions
   GROUP BY
    senderResellerId
   HAVING
    t_amount > 10000 ) AS dum;
```

So far, I could group by senderResellerId by term aggregation. But when I apply filters, it does not work as expected.

**Elastic Request**

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "reseller_sale_sum": {
      "aggs": {
        "sales": {
          "aggregations": {
            "reseller_sale": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "requestAmountValue"
              }
            }
          }, 
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "reseller_sale": { 
                "gte": 10000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, 
      "terms": {
        "field": "senderResellerId", 
        "order": {
          "sales>reseller_sale": "desc"
        }, 
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  }, 
  "ext": {}, 
  "query": {  "match_all": {} }, 
  "size": 0
}
```

**Actual Response**

```
{
  "took" : 21,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 150824,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "reseller_sale_sum" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 149609,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "RES0000000004",
          "doc_count" : 8,
          "sales" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "reseller_sale" : {
              "value" : 0.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "RES0000000005",
          "doc_count" : 39,
          "sales" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "reseller_sale" : {
              "value" : 0.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "RES0000000006",
          "doc_count" : 57,
          "sales" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "reseller_sale" : {
              "value" : 0.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "RES0000000007",
          "doc_count" : 134,
          "sales" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "reseller_sale" : {
              "value" : 0.0
            }
          }
        }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from above response, it is returning resellers but the *reseller_sale* aggregation is zero in results.

More details are [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sql-like-group-by-and-having/104705).

Comment: May you please provide the ES mapping you are using and a couple of example documents?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Mapping is updated here. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sql-like-group-by-and-having/104705

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Implementation of [HAVING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL))-like behavior

You may use one of the [`pipeline aggregations`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html), namely [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html). The query would look like this:

```
POST my_index/tdrs/_search
{
   "aggregations": {
      "reseller_sale_sum": {
         "aggregations": {
            "sales": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "requestAmountValue"
               }
            },
            "max_sales": {
               "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "var1": "sales"
                  },
                  "script": "params.var1 > 10000"
               }
            }
         },
         "terms": {
            "field": "senderResellerId",
            "order": {
               "sales": "desc"
            },
            "size": 5
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

After putting the following documents in the index:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "tdrs",
        "_id": "AV9Yh5F-dSw48Z0DWDys",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "requestAmountValue": 7000,
           "senderResellerId": "ID_1"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "tdrs",
        "_id": "AV9Yh684dSw48Z0DWDyt",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "requestAmountValue": 5000,
           "senderResellerId": "ID_1"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "tdrs",
        "_id": "AV9Yh8TBdSw48Z0DWDyu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "requestAmountValue": 1000,
           "senderResellerId": "ID_2"
        }
     }
  ]
```

The result of the query is:

```
"aggregations": {
      "reseller_sale_sum": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "ID_1",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "sales": {
                  "value": 12000
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

I.e. only those `senderResellerId` whose cumulative sales are `>10000`.

#### Counting the buckets

To implement an equivalent of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (... HAVING)` one may use a combination of [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) with [sum bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html). Though there seems to be no direct way to count how many buckets did `bucket_selector` actually select, we may define a `bucket_script` that produces `0` or `1` depending on a condition, and `sum_bucket` that produces its `sum`:

```
POST my_index/tdrs/_search
{
   "aggregations": {
      "reseller_sale_sum": {
         "aggregations": {
            "sales": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "requestAmountValue"
               }
            },
            "max_sales": {
               "bucket_script": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "var1": "sales"
                  },
                  "script": "if (params.var1 > 10000) { 1 } else { 0 }"
               }
            }
         },
         "terms": {
            "field": "senderResellerId",
            "order": {
               "sales": "desc"
            }
         }
      },
      "max_sales_stats": {
         "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "reseller_sale_sum>max_sales"
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

The output will be:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "reseller_sale_sum": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            ...
         ]
      },
      "max_sales_stats": {
         "value": 1
      }
   }
```

The desired bucket count is located in `max_sales_stats.value`.

#### Important considerations

I have to point out 2 things:

1. The feature is experimental (as of ES 5.6 it is still experimental, though it was added in [2.0.0-beta1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-pipeline.html).)
2. pipeline aggregations are applied on the result of previous aggregations:

> Pipeline aggregations work on the outputs produced from other aggregations rather than
> from document sets, adding information to the output tree.

This means that `bucket_selector` aggregation will be applied after and on the result of `terms` aggregation on `senderResellerId`. For example, if there are more `senderResellerId` than `size` of `terms` aggregation defines, you will not get **all** the ids in the collection with `sum(sales) > 10000`, but only those that appear in the output of `terms` aggregation. Consider using sorting and/or set sufficient `size` parameter.

This also applies for the second case, `COUNT() (... HAVING)`, which will only count those buckets that are actually present in the output of aggregation.

In case this query is too heavy or the number of buckets too big, consider [denormalizing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) your data or store this sum directly in the document, so you can use plain [`range`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) query to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Can you tell me how to calculate the count of the buckets, if I mention INT_MAX as my size?

Comment: I just want the count of buckets, not the content of buckets.

Comment: @chuckskull Right, I missed that point in the original answer. Please check again!

Comment: @chuckskull how can I mention INT_MAX as my size?

Comment: @Akram Manually by writing the value instead of INT_MAX. AFAIK.

Comment: @chuckskull  thanks, I would like the get only the count of the buckets and not the contents?

Comment: @Akram You can use [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to do that.

Comment: @Nicolay thanks but how can I modify your original answer to Implement cardinality aggregation and then display only the count of the buckets

Comment: @Akram now I think I understand what you need. If you only care about the `COUNT(*)` part, and wish to omit the buckets it was counted upon, you can use [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) to specify which part of the response to show. Please tell me if that works for you, I will add it to the answer then.

Comment: @Nicolay I tried the filter_path  aggregations.**.value  it's just performing the filter on the response but this is still generating all the buckets on the server ...

Comment: @Akram if you need to filter on the generated buckets (the `HAVING` part), ES has to generate them, I don't think there's a way around this. Maybe you can ask another question with your setup exactly? It would be easier to answer having a description and a couple of examples.