# Hotel date filter: return only hotels that respect minimum stay period specified for range (SQL or Elasticsearch)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, elasticsearch

Let's say you have a database of Hotels. Each hotel creates many rates in the database, each with a `from_date` and `to_date`. The rates are guaranteed to never overlap.

In each rate, hotel manager can set the minimum stay for that period. For example, from December 1st to January 30th, the minimum stay is 10 nights.

Now a traveler inputs his dates, for example, December 25 to January 1st. In this case, this hotel should **not** be returned in the results, because there's a rate from December 1st to January 30th that specifies only stays of at least 10 nights are welcome.

I can't think of a way of querying this database (either using SQL or Elasticsearch, which is our search engine as of now) to avoid returning hotels that have a higher minimum stay in that date range.

In SQL, I would explore a path `joining` the Hotels table with the rates table, using a `WHERE` to get the rates that overlap the dates desired by the traveler (probably using the algo `(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)`), plus an aggregate function like `MAX()` to get the maximum `min_stay` of the found rates, and finally a `HAVING` to specify it should be > then the # of nights that exists in the range provided by the traveler.

But even this path is obscure to me since when I join a table I would exclude Hotels without any rates configured, and that's not desired; maybe a left outer join? And how to translate that to elasticsearch should be an even greater challenge (maybe using something like bucket aggregations described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46953947/1290457)

Comment: Which method do you use to determine minimum stay? Stay through (maximum over all dates) or just the checkin date?

Comment: @SalmanA maximum over all dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough outline of the query. It assumes that the end date for rates are inclusive.

```
SET @checkin  = '2018-12-25';
SET @checkout = '2019-01-01';
SET @date1    = @checkin;
SET @date2    = @checkout - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
SET @nights   = DATEDIFF(@checkout, @checkin);

SELECT *
FROM hotels
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM hotel_rates
    WHERE hotel_id = hotels.id
    AND @date2 >= from_date AND to_date >= @date1
    AND min_stay > @nights
)
```

It checks that for each hotel, no rate exists that intersects the given date range and requires a min stay greater than number of nights.

Comment: Salman that's a rough outline I assumed as well, I appreciate it! But doesn't your query return hotel_ids, instead of hotels from the hotels table? Also, if that's the case, and we need to join the tables, would a left outer join be the way to go to avoid excluding hotels that haven't configured any hotel_rates ? (If the hotel manager hasn't informed any hotel_rates with min stay, the hotel should NOT be excluded from the results).

Comment: @sandre89 I've simplified the query.

Comment: great logic and code, I appreciate it a lot! I already upvoted your answer and I'm going to wait for a couple of days to see if any solutions come up regarding ElasticSearch. Thanks for now!