# SQL like GROUP BY AND HAVING example

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-sql

I am new to ES and i would need to make a query

```
Select value 
from table 
group by value 
having count(distinct(id)) > 1
```

I do not even have areas to start. referencing this [SQL like GROUP BY AND HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908360/sql-like-group-by-and-having) didnt help much.

**Example of Data**

```
------------
Value | id |
------------
val1  | 2  |
val2  | 2  |
val3  | 2  |
val1  | 3  |
------------
```

**Expected returns**

```
----
val1 
----
```

Comment: groupby should be "group by"

Comment: It doesn't make sense to be grouping by `value` and also asserting its distinct count in the `HAVING` clause.  Please add sample input table data along with the output you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i realised that was a bug in my sql statement question. I have rectified it and posted example data

Answer (score 3):

Since you are new to Elasticsearch and, also, looking into SQL, I would suggest having a look at [Elasticsearch-SQL](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-sql). Documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/xpack-sql.html).

Regarding your specific query, you can try the [`translate` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/sql-translate.html) which will give you the Elasticsearch query it will run for a given SQL query. This can be a great starting point for your final Elasticsearch query. Or you can use ES-SQL as is with the `_sql` endpoint to send SQL queries and get back results.

Answer (score 2):

You should be asserting `COUNT(value)` or `COUNT(*)` here:

```
SELECT value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The problem with asserting `COUNT(DISTINCT value) > 1` is that this condition will never be true.  The reason why it will never be true is that after `GROUP BY` finishes, each group will consist of one and only one `Value`.

Comment: I need it to be unique counts. And i need to translate this to an ES query. I have modified my question. there was a bug in my previous question. i am counting on another field

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 Select value 
    from table 
    group by value 
    having count(distinct value) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT value
FROM table
GROUP BY value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[Check this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1a57/2)