# SQL "group by and having" in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a similar problem like described here:
[SQL like GROUP BY AND HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908360/sql-like-group-by-and-having)

My documents all have an array with such entries.

```
performance: 5,    
region: [
      {"weight":37.34405,"label":"United States"},
      {"weight":5.56081,"label":"Japan"},
      {"weight":0.12385,"label":"Australasia"},
      {"weight":0.77158,"label":"Asia - Developed"},
      {"weight":2.42013,"label":"Asia - Emerging"},
      {"weight":3.06209,"label":"Emerging Market"},
      {"weight":95.39525,"label":"Developed Country"},
      {"weight":0,"label":"Not Classified"},
      {"weight":2.04096,"label":"Canada"},
      {"weight":0.38679,"label":"Latin America"},
      {"weight":18.018,"label":"United Kingdom"},
      {"weight":23.90912,"label":"Eurozone"},
      {"weight":7.59103,"label":"Europe - ex Euro"},
      {"weight":0.14624,"label":"Europe - Emerging"},
      {"weight":0.10893,"label":"Africa"},
      {"weight":0.03585,"label":"Middle East"}
    ]
```

In each document the labels are the same but the weight-values are potential different.
My task is to group all the regions where weight is 80+ and do math-stuff with the sum-weight from this group and the performance-value.
In SQL i would simply do a "group by label having weight >= 80" query and got my values, but as a newbee in ES i haven't getting any good results.

Are here kind ES-experts, which could give me some hint for correct mapping and a query, where i get the correct result for group, sum-weight and the performance of each document?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider denormalizing `region` values into separate objects? ES loves flat denormalized data.

Comment: Hi ilvar,
don't know, what you mean with denormalizing.
Made a mapping for `region` which looks like this:

"region": {
   "type": "nested",
   "properties": {
      "label": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
         "keyword": {
            "type":"keyword",
            "ignore_above":256
          }
        }
      },
      "weight": {
        "type": "float"
       }
     }
}

Comment: I mean, do not use `nested` instead create 10+ docs, each with `performance`, `weight` and `label`