# How to filter the top hits aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am doing some queries on an index `products` I have in elasticsearch. I have the following documents in index `products`

```
{ "product_name": "prod-1", "meta": [ { "key": "key1", "value": "value1" }, { "key": "key2", "value": "value2" } ] }
{ "product_name": "prod-2", "meta": [ { "key": "key1", "value": "value1" } ] }
{ "product_name": "prod-2", "meta": [ { "key": "key2", "value": "value2" } ] }
{ "product_name": "prod-3", "meta": [ { "key": "key2", "value": "value2" } ] }
```

What I want now is to get `product_name`s that have both `key1/value1` and `key2/value2` in meta array but not necessarily in the same document. For example, in the above data `prod-1` has both `key1/value1` and `key2/value2` in the same document, so I want `prod-1` in the result. And `prod-2` also has both `key1/value1` and `key2/value2` but in different documents. I want `prod-2` also in the result. `prod-3` has only `key2/value2` even across documents. So, I don't want to get `prod-3` in the results.

I am trying the following apporach

1. Group by product name
2. Then filter the aggregation results to check each product has both `key1/value1` and `key2/value2`

I group them by `product_name` and combine meta fields in each bucket as follows

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "all_meta": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "meta.key",
                "meta.value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result after the above aggregation is effectively the following

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_product" : {
      ...
      "buckets" : [
        {
          ...
          "key" : "prod-2",
          "all_meta" : {
            "hits" : {
              ...
              "hits" : [
                {
                  ....
                  "_source" : {
                    "meta" : [
                      {
                        "value" : "value1",
                        "key" : "key1"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  ....
                  "_source" : {
                    "meta" : [
                      {
                        "value" : "value2",
                        "key" : "key2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          ....
          "key" : "prod-1",
          "all_meta" : {
            "hits" : {
              ....
              "hits" : [
                {
                  ....
                  "_source" : {
                    "meta" : [
                      {
                        "value" : "value1",
                        "key" : "key1"
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : "value2",
                        "key" : "key2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          ....
          "key" : "prod-3",
          "all_meta" : {
            "hits" : {
              ....
              "hits" : [
                {
                  ....
                  "_source" : {
                    "meta" : [
                      {
                        "value" : "value2",
                        "key" : "key2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now, I want to filter values from the above aggrgation and get buckets only when each bucket has both `{ "key": "key1", "value": "value1" }` and `{ "key": "key2", "value": "value2" }` in meta. Something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "buckets.all_meta.hits.hits._source.meta",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "buckets.all_meta.hits.hits._source.meta.key": "key1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "buckets.all_meta.hits.hits._source.meta.value": "value1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "buckets.all_meta.hits.hits._source.meta",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "buckets.all_meta.hits.hits._source.meta.key": "key2"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "buckets.all_meta.hits.hits._source.meta.value": "value2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do the above step. Is it possible to do this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587083/elasticsearch-filter-top-hits-aggregation) stackoverflow question is similar but it doesn't have any answers. Is there any other approach to get the results I want? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you want is to only take into account documents that have both key1/value1 and key2/value2 and aggregate them, right? So you should only have a single bucket for `prod-1`, correct?

Comment: @Val I want to get products that have both key1/value1 and key2/value2 but not necessarily in a single document. Here, prod-2 has both key1/value1 and key2/value2 but in different documents. I want both prod-1 and prod-2 in the results

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. The idea is that in each product bucket, we aggregate all key/value pairs (using a scripted `terms` aggregation) and then using a `bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation, we only select the the product buckets which have two different pairs.

```
POST products/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "meta": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "meta"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "kv": {
              "terms": {
                "script": """
                [doc['meta.key.keyword'].value, doc['meta.value.keyword'].value].join('-')
                """,
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "meta>kv._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.count == 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the results, you can see that we only have `prod-1` and prod-2`:

```
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "prod-2",
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "meta" : {
        "doc_count" : 2,
        "kv" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "key1-value1",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "key2-value2",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key" : "prod-1",
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "meta" : {
        "doc_count" : 2,
        "kv" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "key1-value1",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "key2-value2",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```